# When I upload image as base64 in post request I get error 403

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, dj-rest-auth

When I try to upload an image to the backend using a form with post request, I get a 403 error. I tried adding X-CSRFToken and "Accept": "application/json" to the headers, it didn't help at all. I tried to add the owner to the postBody from the name that I was saving to the localstorage
I don't know where I made a mistake. I use dj-rest-auth for authentication
There is fetch function from frontend:

```
export async function action({ request }) { 
    const data = await request.formData();
    // const file = fileToBase64(data.get('file'))
    console.log(data)
    const postData = { 
      title: data.get('title'),
      image: data.get('base64File'),
    };
    console.log(postData)
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(postData),
    });
    if (response.status === 422 || response.status === 401) {
      
      return response;
    }
  
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw json({ message: 'Could not add image.' }, { status: 500 });
    }
  
    
    const resData = await response.json();
    console.log(resData)
    return redirect('/');
  }
```

There is backend serializer:

```
class PostsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=60, )
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    # creator_id = UserSerializer(many=False, read_only=True).data
    favorites = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, view_name='favorite-detail')
    comments = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, view_name='comment-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['pk', 'url', 'title', 'owner', 'image', 'created_at', 'favorites', 'comments']
```

And view:

```
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsCurrentUserOwnerOrReadOnly]
queryset = Post.objects.all()
serializer_class = PostsSerializer
ordering_fields = ['created_at', 'favorites']
filter_fields = ['title']
search_fields = ['title']
name = 'post-list'

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

If you need the full code here is a link to the repository: https://github.com/Cichyy22/imagur-like-site

Comment: Relevant code should be included in your question, not externally. Please see how to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by editing the request:

```
 export async function action({ request }) { 
    const data = await request.formData();
    // const file = fileToBase64(data.get('file'))
    console.log(data)
    const postData = { 
      title: data.get('title'),
      image: data.get('base64File')
    };
    console.log(postData)
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
        "X-CSRFToken": Cookies.get('csrftoken'),
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(postData),
    });
    if (response.status === 422 || response.status === 401) {
      
      return response;
    }
  
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw json({ message: 'Could not add image.' }, { status: 500 });
    }
  
    
    const resData = await response.json();
    console.log(resData)
    return redirect('/');
  }
```

And by editing the settings file on the backend:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
        'rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter',
        'rest_framework.filters.SearchFilter',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
REST_USE_JWT = True 
JWT_AUTH_COOKIE_USE_CSRF = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Include an input field of type "file" in your form to allow the user to select an image file to upload.

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>


const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();

// Configure multer to store uploaded files in the "uploads" directory
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

// Handle the POST request to upload an image
app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  const image = req.file;
  // Do something with the uploaded image file
  res.send('Image uploaded successfully');
});
```

Comment: In your backend, handle the POST request and retrieve the uploaded image file using a file input parser like multer (if you are using Node.js). Make sure to configure multer to store the uploaded files in a location accessible by your application.

Comment: It wasn't very helpful because of how badly I described the problem, now I've edited the question.